# How to avoid the code that is visible as HTML Title in R Shiny app?

Tags: html, r, shiny

The parameters for the titlePanel function gets displayed as HTML title in R Shiny app. How to avoid this?

[image: titlePanel issue-1]

[image: titlePanel issue-2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid it by defining a title

```
fluidPage(
   title = "TITLE",
   titlePanel(...
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, you want to put a PNG image in your title Panel.
Then you must create a folder called "www" in your shinyapp directory. Moves your png image to this folder. Write this code instead of your titlePanel code:

```
titlePanel(HTML('<img src="Title.png"/ height="90" width="830" > '))
```